# Only else statement of if...else ladder is being executed no matter what the input. Why is this happening?

Tags: java, if-statement, file-handling

Given below is some code to sort the contents of a file in ascending or descending order wher `in` is an object of the `Scanner` class

```
public void sortFile(String fileName)throws IOException
{
    FileReader fin=new FileReader("C:\\File Handling\\"+fileName+".txt");
    BufferedReader bin=new BufferedReader(fin);

    String[] str=new String[100];

    int i=0;
    while((str[i]=bin.readLine())!=null)
        i++;

    Comparator<String> c=Collections.reverseOrder();

    System.out.println("\nIf you want to sort in descending order, enter A");
    System.out.println("If you want to sort in ascending order, enter D");
    System.out.println("Using any other characters or strings will produce an error and exit his method\n");

    String opt=in.next();
    if(opt=="A"||opt=="a")
        Arrays.sort(str,0,i);
    else if(opt=="D"||opt=="d")
        Arrays.sort(str,0,i,c);
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong option");
        main();
    }

    FileWriter fout=new FileWriter("C:\\File Handling\\"+fileName+".txt");
    BufferedWriter bout=new BufferedWriter(fout);
    PrintWriter pout=new PrintWriter(bout);

    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]!=null)
            pout.println(str[i]);
    }

    pout.flush();
    pout.close();
}
```

However upon execution of this code, no matter what value  I assign to the variable `opt`, I always get a message of "Wrong option" and get redirected to the `main()` method.

Why is this happening?

Does anyone have any other suggestions to improve this code in any other aspect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(opt.equals("A")||optopt.equals("a")){...}
else if(opt.equals("D")||opt.equals("d")){...}
else{...}
```

`String` is object so for equaling two string's required `equals` method.

Find a good post - [What’s the difference between equals() and ==?](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/)

Comment: Yes, you need to use the equals() method instead of using == to compare strings.  == works for primitives, or for testing to see if two objects are the same instance.